How to Synchronize ScrollController with ItemScrollController in Flutter? (SingleChildScrollView and ScrollablePositionedList.builder)
How can one synchronize the scrolling between a SingleChildScrollView and a ScrollablePositionedList.builder?
The SingleChildScrollView uses a ScrollController, while the ScrollablePositionedList.builder uses an ItemScrollController. The items in the ScrollablePositionedList.builder have varying heights.
What is the best approach to achieve synchronized scrolling between these two widgets?
Situation: there are two long screens: the first is SingleChildScrollView with a shimmer effect, and the second is a ScrollablePositionedList.builder. Scrolling one should scroll the other in sync. How can this be achieved?

Based on what you said, you can use the addListener method of the ScrollController to listen for changes in the scroll position of a SingleChildScrollView. To change the scroll position of a ScrollablePositionedList, you can use an ItemScrollController. Additionally, you have two other listeners at your disposal: ItemPositionsListener and ScrollOffsetListener. You can experiment with these listeners to scroll the SingleChildScrollView programmatically..
